# XSLT - Moving nodes to a parent node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need a XSLT for moving the "NODES" from CATALOG/NODES/NODE[ 1 ] to CATALOG/NODES/NODE[ 0 ].
I tried everything but nothing did work yet :(

My XML-File:

```
<CATALOG>
<NODES>
<NODE>
<NODES/>
<NODES/>
</NODE>
<NODE>
<NODES/>
<NODES/>
<NODES/>
</NODE>
</NODES>
</CATALOG>
```

Should be this:

```
<CATALOG>
<NODES>
<NODE>
<NODES/>
<NODES/>
<NODES/>
<NODES/>
<NODES/>
</NODE>
</NODES>
</CATALOG>
```

Details of my XML on the picture!

[Moving the NODES up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cbMe.png)

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather ambiguous. AFAICT, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/CATALOG/NODES">
    <xsl:copy>
        <NODE>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="NODE/NODES"/>
        </NODE>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce the expected output, when applied to your input. But that could be just a coincidence.